# how to set up a while loop for

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I need to modify this method so that I can enter multiple points for x and y using a while loop. If the value is out of range of 0 - 290 then the loop needs to exit and print "Done". I just learned while loops and I still don't totally understand how they work. This is my code for that method so far.

```
public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
{


System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");
    //Read x from user
    int x = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Read y from user
    int y = keyboard.nextInt();
    //Plot the point
    new Circle(x,y);
 }
```

If the user enters an x- or y-value that is out of range (i.e., can't be plotted) the
loop should exit WITHOUT plotting the point. The canvas size is 300x300, so
initially any point less than 0 or greater than 290 (your point diameter is 10)
should cause an exit. (This range will change in the next activity.) Print the word
“Done” after exiting the loop.

If the user enters a x- and y-values that in range, you should plot the point. The
loop will continue and allow the user to enter another point.

Note that, for now, point (0,0) will be in the upper left corner and (290,290) will
be in the lower right
this is currently what I am working on for my lab for my first Cs Class.
I tried using the while loop myself but it ended up printing "done" over and over and it took a minute for the program to stop.

Comment: print "done" after the loop

Comment: im not even sure how to properly set up the while loop

Comment: You should read more on while loops and try again on your own.   http://greenteapress.com/thinkjava6/html/thinkjava6008.html#sec82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while loop executes a piece of code until a condition is reached. For example:

```
int number = 0;

while (number < 5) {
    System.out.println(number);
    number++;
}
```

That would print 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. After that, the condition is false because `number == 5`.

In your case, you need to use a `do while`, pseudocode:

```
do {
    //Ask the user for x, y
} while (x >= 0 && x <= 290 && y >= 0 && y <= 290);

System.out.println("Done");
```

More info about while loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: but what if its over 290 or under 0

Comment: do I do if (d < 290)

Comment: That's when the loop will break and the print sentence will be executed.

Comment: I ran my program (I'm using blue J) and nothing is coming up on my screen

Comment: @LizAbbott did you add your code inside the loop or just copy the exact code in the answer?

Comment: i tried both? i think im missing something, whats suppose to be in it? i assumed of what i have

Comment: @LizAbbott please read the example in this answer and the link provided. Try some simple loops, play with the variables, try things until you understand how they work. This site is not really meant for explaining the basics of the Java language, there are plenty of resources out there that already do this and it's easy to try things on your own.

Comment: i got it, it just took some time to mess with it as you said,Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A while looks at a condition, and while that condition is true, it executes the contents. So assuming you want it to execute at least once, you have to preset the variables so your condition is true.  Then prompt the user, then check and either plot the point or exit.

```
int x=0;
int y=0;

// sorry, i like to use lots of parens to make *sure* of what
// is being compared
while ((x>=0)&&(x<291)&&(y>=0)&&(y<291)){

// run your prompt and input here
// be sure to deal with invalid input (a string, decimals, etc)
// if values are within tolerance then plot the point
// else print done

} // end of while loop
```